# AppleScript and Fastlane

Tags: applescript, fastlane

How can I get AppleScript to run fastlane gym command?

```
set pathToWorkspace to choose folder with prompt "Select Your Workspace"

do shell script "cd " & pathToWorkspace's POSIX path's quoted form
do shell script "fastlane gym"
```

It throws an error - command not found

Googleing about I found that I need to add the actual path for the command but I am a noob at scripting and not sure what what the path would be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes you need the full path (the location on disk) to the `fastlane` executable or you need to add the path to the enclosing folder to the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: The **PATH** passed to the `do shell script` _command_ is `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`, and as such any program you want to execute must either be in that **PATH** or you need to use the _fully qualified pathname_ of the program to be executed in your _command line_.

Comment: Adding the programs path to the **PATH** used by a _normal shell_ will not do any good in the _environment passed_ to the _shell_ with the `do shell script` _command_. One could of course make the _command line_ of a `do shell script` _command_ a _compound command_ where you first set the **PATH** followed by a semi-colon and then the _command_ to be executed.